# Get-ChildItem into Powershell ListBox GUI

Tags: powershell, user-interface, listbox, get-childitem

I am trying to find out how I can put the output of an Get-ChildItem into a ListBox.

My idea is, that I want to list the contents of one folder as an Drop-Down Menu within a small Powershell Window. The function then should run the selected file with predefined parameters.

Do you have any idea how to accomplish that?

I tried setting the values of Get-ChildItem as a variable, but then all I get is everything in one line and as one single option.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `$selectedFile = Get-ChildItem | Out-GridView -OutputMode Single` ... shows the files in a popup window, lets you select one and saves the selected file information in variable `$selectedFile`.

Comment: "The function then should run the selected file" - what kinds of files are these? PowerShell scripts? Executables? Something else?

Comment: @zett42 Thanks for this solution. It worked exactly as I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Out-GridView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-gridview) to show the files in a popup dialog which lets you select a file and return the selection.

```
$selectedFile = Get-ChildItem | Out-GridView -Title 'Select a file' -OutputMode Single

Write-Host "Selected file: $($selectedFile.Name)"
```

Use [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) to change which columns are shown by `Out-GridView`:

```
$selectedFile = Get-ChildItem | Select-Object Name, LastWriteTime | Out-GridView -Title 'Select a file' -OutputMode Single

Write-Host "Selected file: $($selectedFile.Name)"
```