# How can I create a selection menu using PowerShell WinForms?

Tags: powershell, winforms, menu

I got a list of filenames (items) in a string, like this:

file1
file2
file3
file4

etc...

and I want to put them into some kind of selection menu, like in GUI [void] $listBox.Items.Add('$string') or something, I don't know how to do that, someone to help? The string is as is row by row, pure filename without spaces.

Thanks !

I tried to make interactive menu from a powershell string to select one item from the menu.

Comment: You forgot to include your failed attempt :)

Comment: @Ivan Benishek you can try this  $filesVar | foreach-object {[void] $listbox.items.Add($_)}

Comment: It is not WinForms, but as you not showing any details or an attempt to create a [mcve], I would concider this solution: [Get-ChildItem into Powershell ListBox GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71236008/1701026)

Answer (score 0):

Ok real quick:
Inspired by this [article](https://petri.com/more-choices-powershell/) about the choisedescription class:

```
 $coll = @()
Get-Content -Path "C:\full\path\to\your\files.txt" | ForEach-Object { 
    $d = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription]::new("$_")
    $coll+=$d
}
$r = $host.ui.PromptForChoice("Your Options","Select a choice",$coll,0)
```

Copy that into powershell ISE, adjust the file path and run it.